# Angular : Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, datatable, angular-material

I'm trying to use websockets in my Angular application with data table component

On every add I run `conect()` function to update content on the client side.

```
import * as io from "socket.io-client";

@Component({
  selector: "app-liste-projets",
  templateUrl: "./liste-projets.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./liste-projets.component.css"]
})
export class ListeProjetsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private ajoutProj: AjoutprojService) {}
...


}
export class UserDataSource extends DataSource<any> {

  constructor(private ajoutProj: AjoutprojService) {
    super();
  }
  socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:8080');

  connect():Observable<NouveauProjet[]> {
    var data= this.ajoutProj.getAllProj();

    return data;

  }
  this.socket.on("add", ()=>{
    this.connect()      })
}
```

I get this error on the line `this.socket.on..` :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
export class UserDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
   private socket: SocketIOClient.Socket;
  constructor(private ajoutProj: AjoutprojService) {   
    super();

  }
  connect():Observable<NouveauProjet[]> {
    this.socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080')
    this.socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('WidgetSocket: Opened a new socket connection', this.socket.id);
    });
    var data= this.ajoutProj.getAllProj();
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this error `Cannot find namespace 'SocketIOClient'`